# Propagating cascading onDelete foreign key constraint using sequelize and MSSQL

Tags: javascript, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, sequelize.js

I have a problem creating foreign key onDelete constraint using Sequelize on MSSQL db.

This is my use case: each company can have multiple users and those users can create multiple requests. Some requests can be created without a reference to the user, which is why I have both references to company and user in the request model. I want to achieve that once a company is deleted, all users from the company are deleted and all requests from the company are deleted.

These are my models defined in Sequelize:

Company model:

```
const CompanyModel = sequelize.define('company', {
  ... some props ...   
});

CompanyModel.associate = function (models) {
  CompanyModel.hasMany(models.user, {
    as: 'users',
    foreignKey: 'companyId',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  });

  CompanyModel.hasMany(models.request, {
    as: 'requests',
    foreignKey: 'companyId',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  });
};
```

User model:

```
const UserModel = sequelize.define('user', {
  ... some props ...   
});

UserModel.associate = function (models) {
  UserModel.belongsTo(models.company, {
    as: 'company',
    foreignKey: 'companyId',
  });

  UserModel.hasMany(models.request, {
    as: 'requests',
    foreignKey: 'userId',
  });
};
```

Request model:

```
const RequestModel = sequelize.define('request', {
  ... some props ...   
});

RequestModel.associate = function (models) {
  RequestModel.belongsTo(models.company, {
    as: 'company',
    foreignKey: 'companyId',
  });

  RequestModel.belongsTo(models.user, {
    as: 'user',
    foreignKey: 'userId',
  });
};
```

However, when I try to sync my database, this is the error I'm getting:

```
RequestError: Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors
'IF OBJECT_ID(\'[request]\', \'U\') IS NULL CREATE TABLE [request] ([id] CHAR(36) , ... some props ..., [companyId] CHAR(36) NULL, [userId] CHAR(36) NULL, PRIMARY KEY ([id]), FOREIGN KEY ([companyId]) REFERENCES [company] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY ([userId]) REFERENCES [user] ([id]) ON DELETE SET NULL);'
```

If I comment the relationship to the user inside of the request model then syncing of the databases passes. The same thing happens if I comment onDelete foreign key constraint inside of the company model for the user. The foreign key constraint for request doesn't matter. I guess, the problem is that deleting company will delete user which might be the creator of the request. The logic is that those requests will be deleted as well, but the database cannot know if only users from the same company (which will be deleted) will be the owners of requests deleted as well for the company.

I've also tried setting `allowNull` to foreign key for the user in request model, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on what should I do? I need to achieve that deleting a company deletes its users and requests.